# How to make airflow scheduling trigger on start_date instead of execution_date (make execution_date equal to start_date)?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

From https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html :

> Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run
>   stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In
>   other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has
>   ended.

This feature is very hurt .

For example I have etl job which run every day, schedule_interval is `0 1 * * *`, so it will trigger 2019-09-22 01:00:00 job on 2019-09-23 01:00:00 . But my etl is processing all data before start_date ,  means data range is between (history, 2019-09-23 00:00:00) , and we can't use `datetime.now()` because this is unable to reproduce. This force me add 1 day to execution_date:

```py
etl_end_time = "{{ (execution_date + macros.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') }}"
```

However, when I need run a job with schedule_interval `45 2,3,4,5,6 * * *` , the `2019-09-22 06:45:00` job would run on `2019-09-23 02:45:00`, which is one day after execution_date (next execution time) .  Instead of adding a day, I had to changed schedule_interval `45 2,3,4,5,6,7  * * *` and put a dummy operator on last run.
And in this situation , you don't need add one day to execution_date , this means you have to define two `etl_end_time` to represent a same date in jobs with different schedule_interval .

All these are very uncomfortable for me , is there any config or built-in method to make execution_date equal to start_date ? Or I have to modify airflow source code ...

Answer (score 1):

for a scheduled run, **next_execution_date** will return the exact time when it triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I found there's a pr 
https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5787

> This change introduces the attribute schedule_interval_edge, a string
>   containing either 'start' or 'end', to DAGs. The scheduler uses the
>   value to determining if a DAG should be scheduled at the start or the
>   end of the schedule interval.
>
> A parameter with the same name was also added to the
>   default_airflow.cfg in the [scheduler] section.

I have taked codes in this pr.